# Language based .htaccess forwarding

Tags: .htaccess

I added the code below to .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.website.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://nl.website.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^tr [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://tr.website.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(en|nl|tr)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The code redirects to Turkish and Dutch subdomains, depending on the language entered from the browser.

The English site at www is opened in English and other languages.

However, if the user voluntarily changes the language and returns to the home page, .htaccess redirects to the browser language again.

My request is to keep the selection of the page in the changed language.

Anyone know how I can do it?

Comment: Do you only have a single "homepage" URL? Your redirects only redirect the homepage? However, your rewrite at the end is looking for the language code in the URL-path?

Comment: The only thing you can do, is _ignore_ any Accept-Language, when the user is requesting one of those language specific domains to begin with. So if they are explicitly requesting `tr.website.com`, then let them stay there, no matter what the Accept-Language might say. Or in other words, only when they requested `www.website.com`, _may_ you redirect elsewhere based on the language. Of course this will not work for English in your setup, because for that, you don't have a language subdomain, only the general `www`.

Comment: Thank you for replies. I don't have only ONE homepage. I have three homepage for each language.